# Pass parameter from dialog to custom worklow activity CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I have a simple custom workflow activity with the following parameter:

`[Input("String")]
public InArgument<string> String { get; set; }`

In the execute method I only have a throw InvalidPluginExecutionException to show me the value of Sring:

```
throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(String.Get(executionContext));
```

Then I created a dialog in crm 2016 with a page that asks for a text value and then I invoke the custom workflow activity with the value the user entered in the dialog.

[image]

[image]

But when executing after entering the text parameter the dialog gives an error when passing the value to the custom workflow activity:

[image]

[image]

Can somebody tell me what's wrong, the workflow activity parameter is just a string and the input in the dialog is also a string. If I take the parameter from the workflow and stop passing the argument from the dialog it runs as expected. I have also tried other types of InArguments ex.: int.

Comment: Isn't the error message because all the workflow does is throw an exception" `throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(String.Get(executionContext));` ? And what do you mean by `if I take the parameter from the workflow and stop passing the argument` ?

Comment: No, the problem is not the exception because the workflow doesn't even run. As I said if I make the workflow without the InArgument String property, that is, without any parameter and throw a message like "It got here" the workflow runs as expected while invoked by the dialog.

Comment: I quickly re-created the dialog with a workflow, exactly like the one you posted and the workflow triggered as expected. Maybe try restarting IIS? or if you are on-line increase the assembly version to force CRM to refresh the assembly?

Comment: I restarted IIS and also increased the assembly version but it's still giving the error. :( I'm going to try on another crm server to see if the problem is in this one.

Comment: As you are on-prem, turn on tracing, read the logs, they almost always point you in the right direction even if they aren't obvious.